# Delet older files if more than 25 files

Tags: php

I have a webcam that uploads pictures to a web folder and I have a script that delets all files older than 1 day, I would like to change this script to keep only 25 images and than delet the older ones.

```
<?
$days = 0;
$dir ='gallery-images/';

$nofiles = 0;

    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (( $file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
        if ( $file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir($dir.'/'.$file) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ((time() - filemtime($dir.'/'.$file)) > ($days * 86400)) { //86400
            $nofiles++;
            unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
            echo "Deletado -- $dir$file \r\n";
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo "Total files deleted: $nofiles \r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (25 < $nofiles) unlink();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an array containing all the files, with the key being the file name and the value the the modification date. Using `uasort` you can than sort by that date. The last step is simple, remove the 25 newest files from the array and delete all remaining files.